# Recaptcha graphic being display incorrectly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

This is the default `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` being displayed on my page:

[image: ugly captcha]

I've tried a bunch with styles, I think the following was the most promising, but no luck:

```
#recaptcha_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) {
  height:18px !important;
}
```

Can anyone give me some guidance?  Thanks.

The html for the captcha looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just add below given CSS in .css file and it will solve your issue. You can change `line-height`s value according to your needs.

```css
.recaptchatable {
    line-height: 12px;
}
```